# how to load different class (definition) instead of requested one, keeping the same name

Tags: java, class, classloader

There is an example:

```
package bar;

public class Bar {

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Bar: " + getClass().getName());
    }

}


package baz;

public class Baz {

    public void doSomething() { // note the same signature
        System.out.println("Baz: "  + getClass().getName());
    }

}


package foo;

public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("bar.Bar", false, new MimicClassLoader(
                Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()));
        // must print "Baz: bar.Bar"
        new bar.Bar().doSomething();
    }

}


package foo;

public class MimicClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    public MimicClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
        super(parent);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        if ("bar.Bar".equals(name)) {
            name = "baz.Baz";
        }
        return super.loadClass(name);
    }

}
```

I tried the above code, but it doesn't work for me. The exception is thrown:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bar/Bar

Does the class definition contains the name of the class? Is there are any ways to change it during loading process?

**UPDATE**

I have found a way to modify the class name using Javassist library:

```
public class MimicClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    public MimicClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
        super(parent);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        if ("bar.Bar".equals(name)) {
            byte[] bytes;
            try {
                bytes = javassist.ClassPool.getDefault()
                        .getAndRename("baz.Baz", "bar.Bar").toBytecode();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            Class<?> clazz = defineClass(name, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            // prints "Baz: bar.Bar"
            // clazz.getMethod("doSomething").invoke(clazz.newInstance());
            return clazz;
        }
        return getParent().loadClass(name);
    }

}
```

But when using `new Bar().doSomething()` it still prints "Bar: bar.Bar".
I think I have missed up some code so there are two classes with the same name exist (the original one and the renamed copy of baz.Baz).

Comment: try to remove packagename. Instead of bar.Bar, just Bar and Instead of baz.Baz, just Baz. Let me know if it works. Are you also sure that Bar/Baz is part of classpath?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you can not change the class name as you are doing in this case. Class.forName() validates your loaded class from one you requested and fails.You can directly load your class with class loader you define.

Comment: In your case you can use  Class<?> clazz=     new MimicClassLoader(
                Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()).loadClass("bar.Bar");